# How to crop resize image in Java?

Tags: java, swing

When I set the image with actual size onto a panel and cropping using mouse it's working fine but when I resize image onto panel and cropping it's getting wrong cropping image. How to crop resize image using mouse?

```
  int x = Math.min(p1.x, p2.x);
  int y = Math.min(p1.y, p2.y);
  int w = Math.abs(p1.x - p2.x);
  int h = Math.abs(p1.y - p2.y);
  BufferedImage dest = image.getSubimage(x,y,w,h)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `How to crop resize image using mouse?` - the same way you crop the original image.  `but when i resize image onto panel ` You just need to make sure you reference the "resize" image when you do the cropping. Post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem if you need more help.

Comment: but i select the area from resize image and cropping from that original image

Comment: `cropping from that original image` - that is my point. Don't do this. You need to crop from the resized image!!! This is the image that is now visible on the panel. If you want to crop from the original image then you will need to calculate the x/y scale factors of the two images. Then you will need to adjust the x/y/width/height values by these scale factors.

Comment: Thanks but I am new in this .Can suggest me some examples or tutorials related to this?

Comment: @shrishri, `Can suggest me some examples or tutorials related to this?` -  Related to what? I suggest two approaches 1) which is simple as you just keep a reference to the resized image so you can crop it if you wish and 2) use basic math to calculate the scale factor between the original and resized images. In any case I already provided more details for the second approach in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to crop from the original image then you will need to calculate the x/y scale factors of the two images. Then you will need to adjust the x/y/width/height values by these scale factors.

So if your original image is 400 x 100 and the resized image is 100 x 100 you would do something like:

```
double xScale = originalImageWidth / resizeImageWidth = 400 / 100 = 4.
```

So now if the cropping rectangle on the resized image is (10, 10, 20, 30);

Then you need to calculate your values something like:

```
int x = rectangle.x * xScale;
int width = rectangle.width * xScale;

image.getSubImage(x, y, width, height);
```

You would obviously need to calculate the y / height values using the y scaling factor.

Comment: by this method i am getting wrong cropping image because i am getting scaling value into point and when i multiply to x,y,w,h it will take integer value that  means a point gap is giving wrong cropping.

Comment: Post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. I have no idea what you are doing.